# Unrecoverable system error when try to install Kali Linux on VirtualBox running on Windows 7

Tags: linux, virtualbox, backtrack

Downloaded  kali-linux-1.0.2-i386.torrent and mounted ISO on a virtual drive.

Followed directions on http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install  to install Kali on VirtualBox running on Windows 7.  When I try to boot in regular mode I get the Kali splash screen and then the error:

> Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
>   A problem has occurred and the system can't recover.  Please contact a system administrator.

I can boot in recovery mode, but I'm unsure what I should try next.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this as well with Kali 1.0.3 (amd64) on VirtualBox.

I encountered the error at the end of the install as well as on reboot.

Things I tried:

- I enabled PAE/NX (default was off), but did not effect a change.
- I noticed that the error was issued by the window manager.  CTRL-ALT-F2 will bring to a text console.
- Using `df -h`, I could see that my virtual hard drive (8GB) was full.

I reinstalled with a fresh 16GB (as opposed to 8GB recommended by the tutorial) virtual HDD, and it now seems to be running fine so far.  (note: PAE/NX was left enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've enabled PAE/NX under the System/Processor settings tab in VirtualBox.

Comment: Can you maybe describe a little more in detail on how this is done?

Comment: PAE/NX was enabled.  And I followed the directions in the link exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a little late but for other people check the minimum requirements for kali @

http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install

the minimum disk space requirements for kali is 10 GB now so when you create a virtual machine the default space is 8 GB so increase it to anything above 10 GB (my suggestion) should fix the problem.

posted Aug 15, 2014